# Python Selenium How to find elements by XPATH with info from TAG and SUB TAG

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

HTML:

```
<div id="related">
      <a class="123" href="url">
            <h3 class="456">
              <span id="id00" aria-label="TEXT HERE">
              </span>
            </h3>
        </a>

       <a class="123" href="url">
            <h3 class="456">
              <span id="id00" aria-label="NOT HERE">
              </span>
            </h3>
        </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find & click on <a (inside the `div id="related"` with `class="123"` AND where SPAN `aria-label` contains "TEXT"

```
 items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='related']//a[@class='123'][contains(@href, 'url')]//span[contains(@aria-label, 'TEXT']")
```

But it's not finding the href, it's only finding the span.

then I want to do:

```
items[3].click()
```

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath has some typo problems.
Try this:

```py
 items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='related']//a[@class='123'][contains(@href,'watch?v=')]//span[contains(@aria-label,'TEXT')]")
```

This will give you the `span` element inside the presented block.
To locate the `a` element you should use another XPath.
**UPD**
To find all the `a` elements inside `div` with `@id='related'` and containing `span` with specific `aria-label` attribute can be clearly translated to XPath like this:

```py
 items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='related']//a[@class='123' and .//span[contains(@aria-label,'TEXT')]]")
```

Comment: Thank you, the typo works...  but how do I get the a after to click.
 do another  `items.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'url)]`

I tried, but I can't click on `items[3].click()` for example

Comment: I think it would help us understand the problem if you provided more html elements than just the one `<a>` tag. Provide more instances of the `<a>` tags you would expect to be present @user3011784

Comment: @user3011784 the `items` elements here are internal `span` elements. You can not search for `a` elements inside these `span`s since `span` is inside the `a`, not the opposite

Comment: I edited the question... how can I find all the  <a  that contains a span with a specific area-label... I understand the find_elements I used only finds the span... but I don't know how to find all the <a

Comment: I see. Please see my updated answer